# Why a function in my JavaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner and I am learning JavaScript. I am trying to make a To-do App with JavaScript. Almost every function is working perfectly. But a function named `doneTask` at line 36 is not working. I tried so much to find out the problem but failed.

My codes:

```js
let formEL = document.querySelector('form')
formEL.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitForm)
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', taskManagement)
document.querySelector('.clear-all').addEventListener('click', clearAll)

function handleSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let inputEl = document.querySelector('input')
    if (inputEl.value != '') {
        addToDo(inputEl.value)
    }
    inputEl.value = ''
}

function taskManagement(e) {
    if (e.target.name == 'done') {
        doneTask(e)
    }
    if (e.target.name == 'delete') {
        deleteTask(e)
    }
}

function addToDo(todo) {
    let ulEl = document.querySelector('ul')
    let liEl = document.createElement('li')
    liEl.innerHTML = `
        <span>${todo}</span>
        <button class="done" name="done">Done</button>
        <button class="delete" name="delete">Delete</button>
    `
    ulEl.appendChild(liEl)
}

// ********** This function is not working **********
function doneTask(e) {
    let taskEl = e.target.parentNode
    if(taskEl.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        taskEl.style.textDecoration = 'none'
    } else {
        taskEl.style.textDecoration == 'line-through'
    }
}

function deleteTask(e) {
    let taskEl = e.target.parentNode
    taskEl.remove()
}

function clearAll(e) {
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = ''
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
}
body {
    background: #8854d0;
}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff
}
img {
    width: 60px;
}
hr {
    margin: 0.5rem 0 2rem 0;
}
form {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.add-btn {
    padding: 6px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
input {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.todo {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted lightgrey;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
    display: flex;
}
span {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.done, .delete {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding: 5px;
    /* pointer-events: none; */
}
.delete {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.clear-all {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png">
    <!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>To-Do App | Dabananda Mitra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <a href="https://todo-dm.netlify.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="./favicon.png" alt="To-DoAppLogo">
            </a>
            <h1>Make your list here</h1>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your task name here...">
                <button class="add-btn" type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
            <div class="todo">
                <ul></ul>
                <a class="clear-all" id="clear-all">Clear all</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- --------------- JavaScript --------------- -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the problem?

How can I fix the problem?

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What is not working? is it not being called? is it throwing an error?

Comment: There is no error showing in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use assignment operator`=` instead of the comparison operator `==`

```
function doneTask(e) {
let taskEl = e.target.parentNode
if(taskEl.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
    taskEl.style.textDecoration = 'none'
} else {
    taskEl.style.textDecoration = 'line-through' // <-- change here `==` to '='
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

According to @deepu-reghunath answer,
style **line-through** is applying on whole **li** element, which is fine if you are okay with it but **line-through** should be apply on only **span** element which contains the text.
`==` is comparison operator
`=` is assignment operator

So more suitable answer will be:

```
function doneTask(e) {
    console.log(e, "event");
    let taskEl = e.target.parentNode.childNodes[1]; // childNodes[1] for getting span element
    if (taskEl.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        taskEl.style.textDecoration = 'none'
    } else {
        taskEl.style.textDecoration = 'line-through' // change `==` to '='
    }
}
```